# pdo_mysql unable to create mysqld.sock file

Tags: php, nginx, mysql.sock

I'm adding PHP (php-fpm) to an existing Nginx Ubuntu 10.04 server and can't get pdo_mysql to work. I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server someplace else, but all the Googling answers I found are in regards to MySQL not working on the local server, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

I don't have mysqld installed, so I'm not sure if I need it, or if there's a way around this? Also I'm wondering if it can't create mysqld.sock because there is mysql user on the server?

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

My PHP connection code:

```
$this->PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->config->getValue('db_host') .
                             ';dbname=' . $this->config->getValue('db_name'),
                             $this->config->getValue('db_user'),
                             $this->config->getValue('db_pass'));
```

My Query line it fails on:

```
$PDOStatement = $this->PDO->query($query);
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: PDO doesn't create the socket file. The MySQL server does. If the socket can't be located, either MySQL isn't running, or your PHP configuration is pointing at the wrong location.

Comment: With the following doc, you may try 'unix_socket' instead of 'db_host' : https://www.php.net/manual/zh/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you should check

- D you have *mysql-client* installed? if you are connecting to remote machine. you don't need mysql running on your box but I think you will still need the client.
- Make sure the host value is correct. Double & triple check
- Lastly, Try connecting manually using command line, by the following command.

> ```
> $ mysql -u <INSERT_USER_HERE> -p -h <INSERT_IP_OF_REMOTE_MACHINE_HERE> <INSERT_DB_NAME_HERE>
> ```

If it does not work. come back with exact error message.

Comment: The `mysql-client` binary is not used, nor needed, by PHP.

Comment: Yup, mysql-client that's what I needed! I couldn't remember for the life of me what it was I needed. Thanks very much Gaurish, appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is attempting to connect to a local MySQL instance.  If your database is on a different remote server, make sure that the the `db_host` value of your configuration file points to the correct hostname of the MySQL server.

You do not need `mysqld` installed, but you do need MySQL client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$this->config->getValue('db_host')` is returning the correct value? The behavior you're describing sounds a lot like it's returning an empty or null value.